# Implementing compositional behaviour for virtual methods

Tags: c++, composition, virtual-functions, virtual-inheritance

Suppose that I have a heirarchy of several classes:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    // Does some work
    void DoStuff() override;
};

class C : public B {
public:
   // Calls B::DoStuff and does other work
   void DoStuff() override;
};
```

It can naively be implemented:

```
void Derived::DoStuff() {
    Base::DoStuff();
    ...
}
```

This implementation has a serious problem, I believe: one always has to remember to call base implementation when overrides.

Alternative:

```
class A {
public:
    void DoStuff() {
        for (auto& func: callbacks_) {
            func(this);
        }
    }

    virtual ~A() = default;
protected:
    template <class T>
    void AddDoStuff(T&& func) {
        callbacks_.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(func));
    }

private:
    template <class... Args>
    using CallbackHolder = std::vector<std::function<void(Args...)>>;

    CallbackHolder<A*> callbacks_;
};
```

Usage:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        AddDoStuff([](A* this_ptr){
            static_cast<Derived*>(this_ptr)->DoStuffImpl();
        });
    }
private:
    void DoStuffImpl();
};
```

However, I believe that it has a good amount of overhead when actually calling `DoStuff()`, as compared to the first implementation. In the use cases which I saw, possibly long costruction of objects is not a problem (one might also try to implement something like "short vector optimization" if he wants).

Also, I believe that 3 definitions for each `DoStuff` method is a little too much boilerplate.

I know that it can be very effectively solved by using inheritance pattern simular to CRTP, and one can hide the template-based solution behind interface class (`A` in the example), but I keep wondering -- shouldn't there be an easier solution?

I'm interested in a good implementation of `call DERIVED implementation FROM BASE, if and only if derived class exists and it has an overriding method` for long inheritance chains (or something equivalent).

Thanks!

Edit:
I am aware of an idea described in @Jarod42's answer, and I don't find it appropriate because I believe that it is ugly for long inheritance chains -- one has to use a different method name for each level of hierarchy.

Comment: *"one always has to remember to call base implementation when overrides."* That is mostly what [Decorator_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) does.

Answer (score 2):

You might change your class `B` to something like:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void DoStuff() final { /*..*/ DoExtraStuff();  }

    virtual void DoExtraStuff() {}
};

class C : public B {
public:
   void DoExtraStuff() override;
};
```

Comment: And if you have inheritance depth of 5, you have 5 different names for methods, which essentially do the same thing. I don't think it's a solution

Comment: If your inheritance depth is 5, and each layer adds more behaviors to the same virtual method, then I think you might want to reconsider the complexity of your inheritance hierarchy in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood correctly but this seems to be addressed pretty good by the ["Make public interface non-virtual, virtualize private functions instead"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm)  advice.

I think it's orignated in the Open-Closed principle. The technique is as-follows:

```
#include <iostream>
class B {
    public:
    void f() {
        before_f();
        f_();
    };

    private:
    void before_f() {
        std::cout << "will always be before f";
    }

    virtual void f_() = 0;
};

class D : public B{
    private:
    void f_() override {
        std::cout << "derived stuff\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    D d;
    d.f();
    return 0;
}
```

You essentially deprive descendant class of overriding public interface, only customize exposed parts. The base class `B` strictly enforces that required method is called before actual implementation in derived might want to do. As a bonus you don't have to remember to call base class.

Of course you could make `f` virtual as well and let `D` decide.

Comment: That's a separation of public facing API from derived class facing API.  Combined with Jarod42's answer, would make for a nice separation of concerns.  Overkill on small projects, but very helpful on large projects.

Comment: @Eljay Yea, I treat [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) dearly. I guess Jarod's answer follow the "There are no problem unsolvable by introduction of another abstraction layer." rule. I.e. just wrap it up.

Comment: You get me wrong. I want a solution for deep inheritance chains. Having a different method name for each level of hierarchy becomes very strange in this situation.